# error 15466 An error during decryption

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xp-cmdshell

I have a stored procedure that runs `xp_cmdshell` with a user with sysadmin right.(it was created by someone else long time ago). For security purposes I need to remove the sysadmin right from this user. 
So I created a proxy account and gave execute privilege to this user on the `xp_cmdshell` (practically followed the steps how to run `xp_cmdshell` with a non sysadmin user ).
But when I run the stored procedure I am getting the below error:

> error number 15466    severity 16  errorline 1    An error occurred during decryption.

I use SQL Server 2008

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely occurring as the old user ( the one with sysdmin rights) had access to the SQL Server Symmetric Keys which are used to encrypt/decrypt keys which the new user does not.

The [Grant Symmetric key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-symmetric-key-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) article provides details and the links at the end provide some good reading.

Comment: i used the following query to see who has access and it is showing no data:

Comment: select u.name, p.permission_name, p.class_desc, 
    object_name(p.major_id) ObjectName, state_desc 
from sys.database_permissions  p join sys.database_principals u
on p.grantee_principal_id = u.principal_id
where class_desc = 'SYMMETRIC_KEYS'